# Macbook pro 2016 144hz

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I own a MacBook Pro 2016 and I want to buy a second monitor with a 2k resolution that runs at 144Hz, is it possible? With what cable?
I've tried to look up on apple support and it says this:
Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
Up to four displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
Thunderbolt 3 digital video output

Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C
VGA, HDMI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately)
Still I cant find anythink about 2k resolution(2560 x 1440).
I want to buy a monitor with a 2k and to run on 144Hz. I don't know if my macbook suports this, if it suports what type of cable do I need?

Comment: If the linked question doesn’t help you, please edit the main body of your post explaining your situation in detail and how you are stuck figuring what will work and we can review the hold/close

Comment: @bmike I tried on line I've got this info:
Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
Up to four displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
Thunderbolt 3 digital video output

Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C
VGA, HDMI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately)
Still nothing about 2k resolution :(